# Build toolbar in RCP programmatically

Tags: java, eclipse, menu, toolbar, rcp

I've looked at this link and followed the steps..
https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_build_menus_and_toolbars_programmatically%3F

For a menu, this works for me:

```
IWorkbenchWindow window = Workbench.getInstance().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
MenuManager menuManager = ((WorkbenchWindow)window).getMenuManager();
MenuManager menu = new MenuManager("Menu &1", "1"); 
menu.add(new Action("Action 1") {}); 
mainMenu.add(menu);
```

The new button with a submenu appears in my top main menu. But I want to add a button to the toolbar. 
I've tried both these but none of them works:

```
IToolBarManager mainToolbar = ((WorkbenchWindow)window).getToolBarManager(); 
mainToolbar.add(new Action("Action 1") {});
```

or

```
ToolBarManager toolbar = new ToolBarManager();
toolbar.add(new Action("Action 1") {}); 
mainToolbar.add(toolbar);
```

i've also tried with CoolBarManager

```
CoolBarManager coolbar = new CoolBarManager(); 
coolbar.add(new Action("Action 1") {}); 
mainToolbar.add(coolbar);
```

What is the correct approach to this?

Comment: If this is an RCP you are writing you should build the menu and toolbar in the ActionBarAdvisor. Using WorkbenchWindow is wrong as that is an internal class and not part of the Eclipse API.